# Как реализовать многопоточность?

Tags: c, многопоточность, сокет, linux

Нужно реализовать многопоточность с помощью `fork()`. Приветствуется любая помощь, хоть ссылку на ресурс, где можно что-то почитать дельное по поводу `fork()`.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
 int server_sockfd, client_sockfd;
 int server_len, client_len;
 struct sockaddr_un server_address;
 struct sockaddr_un client_address;

 server_sockfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

 server_address.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
 strcpy(server_address.sun_path, "/home/coder/dataFaros");
  unlink(server_address.sun_path);
 server_len = sizeof(server_address);
 bind(server_sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_address, server_len);

 listen(server_sockfd, 5);

  har ch;
  printf("server waiting\n");

   client_len = sizeof(client_address);
   client_sockfd = accept(server_sockfd,
    (struct sockaddr *)&client_address, &client_len);
    read(client_sockfd, &ch, 1);
    write(client_sockfd, &ch, 1);
    printf("server waiting\n");
    close(client_sockfd);
}
```

Comment: @kvars232, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

[[@smallFish](/users/22813/smallfish)](/users/22813/smallfish), только вот  `fork`, порождает *новый процесс* (process), а не *поток* (thread) (иногда их называют нитями, чтобы не путать с потоками ввода-вывода (stream)).

Потоки (т.е. параллельно исполняемые последовательности команд в одном адресном пространстве) в Linux создаются вызовом функции `pthread_create`.

Наверное не стоит использовать термин fork вместе с термином поток (т.е. не стоит смешивать процессы с потоками), если Вас на самом деле не интересует  использование fork (т.е. запуск новых процессов) в многопоточной программе (той, в которой уже создано несколько threads).

Для полноты картины следует сказать, что на самом деле в Linux, для запуска и нового процесса и нового потока, используется один и тот же системный вызов `clone` с разным набором параметров.

**Обновление**

[[@kvars232](/users/25319/kvars232)](/users/25319/kvars232), был тут у Вас комментарий

```
метки многопроцессорность или порождение процессов или fork() к сожалению нет. пришлось как то выкручиваться
```

но, куда-то пропал.

Так вот, метки можно "изобретать" самому. Когда создаете вопрос можно либо выбрать уже существующую, либо ввести свою.

Мне кажется, что `процессы` или `multiprocessing` в данном случае лучше чем `многопоточность`.

А `многопроцессорность`  безусловно не подходит, т.к. этот термин связан с железом (количеством CPU), которое здесь явно не важно.

Comment: @avp,спасибо,за потраченное время,думаю теперь разберусь=)

Answer (score 0):

Стандартный [ман](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=fork&category=2&russian=0) никто не отменял. Вставляете в нужном месте - Ваш процесс "раздваивается. По коду возврата проверяете - это родительский процесс или дочерний. Если родительский - продолжаете в цикле ждать новых подключений. Дочерний - обрабатываете подключение.
Вставить, похоже, нужно между accept и read.

Comment: @KoVadim, раздваивается, сохраняя все состояния на момент раздвоения? (Т.е. делается полная копия памяти одного процесса в другой на уровне ОС?)

Comment: Да, делается [практически полная копия](http://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/linux_parallel/node7.html).

Comment: @KoVadim не понял,что вставить между raed() и accept??
fork() что ли??точно не так

Comment: @avp,метки многопроцессорность или порождение процессов или fork() к сожалению нет. пришлось как то выкручиваться

Comment: Да, вставить вызов fork. Конечно, там немного кода ещё будет.

Comment: @KoVadim я не понимаю, зачем создавать второй процесс перед read??
Если несложно, объясни поподробнее, желательно бы с примером кода. =)

Comment: @KoVadim допустим, сделаю, как вы сказали.  
Тогда получается, что listen и accept находятся в одном потоке и подключения не произойдет, соответственно и read не сработает.  
И если несложно, гляньте мой новый вопрос ,он по той же теме, только я немного код преобразовал, и вопрос встал более конкретным.

Comment: @kvars232, типичная (и весьма упрощенная, без проверок) схема сервера

      while (1) {
        int cli_sock = accept(...);
        if (!fork()) // child
           exit (do_action(cli_sock)); // client read/write here
        close(cli_sock);
        while (waitpid(-1, 0, WNOHANG)); // for zombies
      }